# Windows equivalent to udev rules

Tags: windows, usb, udev

(don't know if this question suits to this site, so sorry if not)

There is a possibility to create a link to USB device according to its inner parameters using udev rules. Is there some equivalent to this in Windows?

Comment: I don't think so.  Windows does have the ability to provide user mode access to the device, but it isn't exposed like it is in Linux.